# python last number repeat more than once

Tags: python

My problem is that i dont get the desired output which i want. The list numbers can change as well as the size of the list.

Task:
Complete the method so that it will search through the list passed as a parameter to see if the last value in the list occurs more than once. If the last value occurs more than once, return True (don't print "True"). Otherwise, return False (don't print "False"). If the list is empty, return False.  Call your method from the main method, send it a list, and print the result.

```
def last_repeats(list):
  last_number = list[-1]
  lenght = len(list)
  for x in range (0,lenght-1):
    if list[x] == last_number:
      return True
    else:
      return False
def main():
  list = [0,0,5,5]
  print(last_repeats(list))


############################################
### Don't edit anything below this line. ###
############################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Output I need:

```
True
```

Output i get:

```
False
```

Comment: Consider adding a sentence about what this is supposed to do — *Why* should it return `True`? Also, don't name variables `list` it overwrites a built-in.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you need to put the return false statement outside the for loop.

Comment: @ThomasWeller `len(x) > 1 && x[-2] == x[-1]`

Comment: @Kenny. No it doesn't. It only checks the first character

Comment: All you need is `return last_number in myList[:-1]` or `return myList.count(last_number) > 1`

Comment: @Thomas. Yup. Mark mostly got the right idea.

Comment: the main function should recieve a list as parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning after checking the first one, even though it might be false. Consider your array [0, 0, 5, 5]. the first element 0 != 5, so it immediately returns False.

To fix that, return False after the function ends

```
def last_repeats(lis): # 'list' is a keyword in python
  if len(lis) == 0: return False # Task requirement
  last_number = lis[-1]
  length = len(list) # typo?
  for x in range(length): # range(0, n) == range(n)
    if lis[x] == last_number:
      return True
  return False # So now you have checked every element in the list
def main():
  lis = [0, 0, 5, 5]
  print(last_repeats(lis))


############################################
### Don't edit anything below this line. ###
############################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Also I just read that if the list is empty, it should return False. Currently, the code gives "IndexError". Try to fix it yourself!

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you @Gareth Ma i got it working. I was thinking that this is the problem but i didnt know how to fix it properly!

Comment: @DaniilKharlashko Did you fix the empty list problem? :)

Comment: i know i just wanted to fix this first. I am working on that right now.

Comment: i have tried to fix that but it doesnt work. I have tried counting with len and IF checking if its 0 to return false and that doesnt work.

Comment: @DaniilKharlashko It should? I have added the line `if len(lis) == 0: return False`. Does that not work? Notice that you must put that line before assigning value of `last_number = lis[-1]`, as you're accessing the "last element of lis" there (which is giving the error)

Comment: so you are saying that i cannot check if its empty after the last_number because when i search for the last number in the list it will give me an error which is why it doesnt work correct?

Comment: @DaniilKharlashko exactly. It's like how you can't write (1 / 0) * 0 to get 1, if that makes sense

Comment: Accept maybe? :)

Answer (score 0):

The range of values for [`range(start, stop, \[step\])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) is determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`. So `for x in range(0, lenght - 1)` will go until the *second to last* item. It should be `range(0, lenght)`:

```
def last_repeats(list):
  last_number = list[-1]
  lenght = len(list)
  vreturn = False
  for x in range (0,lenght):
    if list[x] == last_number:
      vreturn = True
  return vreturn
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score 0):

You get the False output because your if statement returns False on the first appearance of a number not equal to value of last_number (i.e the first element in list) and that's because of the 'else' block which is not needed here.

You should change your if statement to just return True inside the loop. False returned outside the loop:

```
for x in range (lenght):
    if list[x] == last_number:
      return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def last_repeats(lis): # 'list' is a keyword in python
  last_number = lis[-1]
  length = len(list) # typo?
  for x in range(length): # range(0, n) == range(n)
    if lis[x] == last_number:
      return True
  return False # So now you have checked every element in the list
def main():
  lis = [0, 0, 5, 5]
  print(last_repeats(lis))


############################################
### Don't edit anything below this line. ###
############################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
def last_repeats(my_list):
    return my_list and my_list[-1] in my_list[:-1]

def main():
    my_list = [0, 0, 5, 5]
    print(last_repeats(my_list))

############################################
### Don't edit anything below this line. ###
############################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the return false statement outside the for loop.

```
def last_repeats(list):
  last_number = list[-1]
  lenght = len(list)
  for x in range (0,lenght-1):
    if list[x] == last_number:
      return True
  return False
def main():
  list = [0,0,5,5]
  print(last_repeats(list))


############################################
### Don't edit anything below this line. ###
############################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Also you do not need the else case. This edit should achieve the purpose you are trying. At present your function returns false as soon as it inquires a non matching element. Which should be only returned false after you have checked uptill second last element.